# Is there a way to get all keys that match a string in a json file's values and output them to a text file?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get all keys' values that equal "url" ignoring nesting from a JSON file and then output them to a text file. How would I go about doing this?

I'm running Python 3.7 and cannot seem to find a solution.

```
r = requests.get('https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json')
j = r.json()
```

The result expected from this would be a text file filled with links from this json file.

```
https://launchermeta.mojang.com/v1/packages/31fa028661857f2e3d3732d07a6d36ec21d6dbdc/a1.2.3_02.json
https://launchermeta.mojang.com/v1/packages/2dbccc4579a4481dc8d72a962d396de044648522/a1.2.3_01.json
https://launchermeta.mojang.com/v1/packages/48f077bf27e0a01a0bb2051e0ac17a96693cb730/a1.2.3.json
etc.
```

Comment: Did you try anything to process `r.json()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `requests` library

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json').json()
url_list = []
for result in response['versions']:
    url_list.append(result['url'])

print(url_list)
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but providing an answer for a question where no effort was shown to solve the question will attract downvotes

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Hey, I'm sorry about this. I was googling for a bit and found no result and if I couldn't find anything I may as well not just make up stuff there's no point to it. Maybe I could've worded this different asking if there was some specific function.

Comment: @Ninsto no worries, my point was you didn't show any efforts in the question, just doing `r.json()` is not helpful for an answerer to help you, hence the question was downvoted and closed, please take from next time :)